# Signed and unsigned integers -- why are bytes treated differently?

Tags: cpu-word, byte, unsigned, signed

I am learning High Level Assembly Language at the moment, and was going over the concept of signed and unsigned integers. It seems simple enough, however getting to sign extension has confused me.

Take the byte 10011010 which I would take to be 154 in decimal. Indeed, using a binary calculator with anything more than word selected shows this as 154 in decimal.

However, if I select the unit to be a byte, and type in 10011010 then suddenly it is treated as -102 in decimal. Whenever I increase it starting from a byte then it is sign extended and will always be -102 in decimal.

If I use anything higher than a byte then it remains 154 in decimal.

Could somebody please explain this seeming disparity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select the unit as a byte the MSB of `10011010` is treated as the signed bit, which makes this one byte signed integer equivalent interpretation to -102 (2's complement).

For integers sized large than 8 bits, say 16 bits the number will be: `0000000010011010` which do not have 1 in MSB therefore it is treated as a positive integer whose integer representation is 154 in decimal. When you convert the 8 bit byte to a higher type the sign extension will preserve the -ve interpretation in the larger length storage too.

Comment: Ahh, I see. 2 Question...on windows calculator if I choose word, and put in 10011010 I get 154 in decimal. Where did you get 512 from? Also, if I want to store 154 in binary in a single byte, this is where I would use an unsigned integer?

Comment: I am sorry , the 512 was a typo, it should be 154. I have fixed it. To store 154 you will need atleast 8 bits of storage. For signed 1 byte integer you have 7 bits for magnitude 1 bit for sign. Therefore you can use an unsigned single byte storage which has 8 bit length and does not interpret the MSB as signed bit, like the `unsigned char` type  in C. Else in other larger formats the magnitude part have mode than 8 bits and therefore you can store +154 in all of them.